# SQL Display the TID and Total Number of Items Sold

Tags: sql

[image]Q:Display the TID and the total number of items (of all products) sold within the transaction for all sales transactions whose total number of items (of all products sold within the transaction is greater than five.

I've tried multiple times, but what I end up doing is adding together the individual purchases rather than the item purchases combined.

Comment: post the query you have written

Comment: there are a number of cases here in stack.. you should be able to find them

Comment: Select TID, Sum(NoOfItems)
From Product, SoldVia
Group By TID

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to compute the `sum` per `TID` and then use the `having` clause to filter those products having sold more than 5 items:

```
select TID, sum(NoOfItems) from soldvia group by TID having sum(NoOfItems) > 5;
```

Comment: Your answer didn't provide any results.